Openning TileJSON file OpenInfraMap in QGIS
I tried to open the OpenInfraMap JSON folder to obtain the data in QGIS.
However, I don't have the extension to add layers from a JSON file: https://openinframap.org/map.json
Would anyone know how to do this?


This question is similar to: Filtering OpenInfraMap vector tiles by layer name in QGIS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, that's not it because I need all the layers in the Json file ...

Please do not add textual data as a picture. Formatting it in a code block would be far more legible.

Yes, just add each of them as shown in the answer to the linked question

Try adding tiles as URL https://openinframap.org/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf from the JSON file via Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Tile Layer...

and get the result like this:

This is QGIS 3.34.8-Prizren.

Yes, it works, but I'd like to be able to see the different layers as shown in the video...
